# Find a solution to a set of equations, within a specified range

Tags: equation-solving

Given the following list

```
myList = {a + 2 g, -2 c d - 3 b f + 2 a g,  d^2 f -  c d g, -2 c^2 - a f, 
  c d f -  c^2 g}
```

of five expressions in the variables `a,b,c,d,f,g`,

I'd like to find a non-zero, integer solution to the set of equations:

```
myList[[i]] ==0
```

for `i=1,2,...,5.`

It's actually enough for me to only look for solutions in which all the variables are integers in the range `[-3,3]`.

Answer (score 2):

```
FindInstance[
 And @@ Thread[myList == 0] && 
 And @@ Thread[-3 <= {a, b, c, d, f, g} <= 3] && 
 And @@ Thread[ {a, b, c, d, f, g} != 0], {a, b, c, d, f, g}, Integers]

(*{{a -> -2, b -> -2, c -> -1, d -> -1, f -> 1, g -> 1}}*)
```

If you want to find more solutions, just add `, 5` after `Integers`, for this problem it seems there are only 4 solutions.

Answer (score 2):

```
myList = {a + 2 g, -2 c d - 3 b f + 2 a g, d^2 f - c d g, -2 c^2 - a f, 
   c d f - c^2 g};

var = Variables[Level[myList, -1]];

soln = Solve[
  {myList == 0, {-3 <= # <= 3, # != 0} & /@ var} // Flatten,
  var, Integers]

{{a -> -2, b -> -2, c -> -1, d -> -1, f -> 1, g -> 1}, {a -> -2, b -> -2, 
  c -> 1, d -> 1, f -> 1, g -> 1}, {a -> 2, b -> 2, c -> -1, d -> -1, f -> -1,
   g -> -1}, {a -> 2, b -> 2, c -> 1, d -> 1, f -> -1, g -> -1}}
```

Verifying solution

```
(myList /. soln) // Union

{{0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}
```